# HTML Copy selected image file to a folder

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make an input button that can copy an image and then paste it into a folder. I tried to do this with some codes that i've searched on internet but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Do you feel like including the code you have tried and the errors (if any) you had?

Comment: and what you are expecting from us?

Comment: The code i've tried was from the internet so if you want i can only put a link here since it not mine    Link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30795620/get-image-and-upload-save-it-in-server-location

Comment: I don't know where is the error since I'm new to this coding language (first time use due to school homework) so I tried to change the address but not thing happened.